# How do I move the navigation bar to right in html?

Tags: html

Here is what I have. What am I missing? I need the nav bar to move to the right by Monday is is currently down the left  side

```
                <html>
               <head>
             <title>HTML and JavaScript </title>
             </head>
             <frameset border="5"rows="60,*">
             <frame name="UpperFrame" noresize src="title.html">
             <frameset  border="5" cols="180,*">
            <frame name="rightframe" noresize src="navbar.html">
            <frame name="leftframe" noresize src="welcome.html">
            </frameset>
           </html>
```

Comment: You mean move it dynamically, or just position it to the right?

Comment: so where is the nav bar ?

Comment: it is down the left side of the page

Comment: Frames not long exist in web standards. They've very old and should not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here is the correct code.

<frameset rows="60,*">
             <frame name="UpperFrame" noresize src="title.html">
                <frameset cols="*,180">
                    <frame name="leftframe" noresize src="welcome.html">
                    <frame name="rightframe" noresize src="navbar.html">
                </frameset>
            </frameset>
```